# How can I deserialize json with Json.Converter

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, json.net, deserialization

I have a json:

```
 "objects": {
                    "user0": {
                        "uid": "1",
                    }
                    "user1": {
                        "uid": "2",
                    }
                    "user2": {
                        "uid": "3",
                    }

                    .....

                    "userN": {
                        "uid": "N",
                    }

                    "venue0": {
                        "id": "1",
                    }
                    "venue1": {
                        "id": "2",
                    }
                    "venue2": {
                        "id": "3",
                    }

                    .....

                    "venueN": {
                        "id": "N",
                    }
             }
```

I have a model:

```
[DataContract]
public class User
{
    [DataMember(Name = "uid")]
    public class string Uid {get; set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class Venue
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public class string Id {get; set;}
}


[DataContract]
public class Objects
{
    [DataMember(Name = "user1")]
    public class User User1 {get; set;}

    [DataMember(Name = "user2")]
    public class User User2 {get; set;}

    [DataMember(Name = "venue1")]
    public class Venue Venue1 {get; set;}

    [DataMember(Name = "venue2")]
    public class Venue Venue2 {get; set;}


    //I can't define all keys of json
    // If the json contain 10000 users or venues, I must declare 10000 properties in class Objects? 
}
```

Can I deserialize the json with the `JsonConverter`?

```
Objects objs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Objects>(json);
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or exception?

Comment: Did you try it? Did it throw an error? Or are you asking how to load the json string to a class that *doesn't* have all User and Venue properties defined?

Comment: the json can contain many users and venues, I don't know how descrcribe models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your data cannot be modeled with a sensible type. You need to use dictionaries and dynamic objects. I managed to deserialize somehow.

Data:

```
{
    "objects": {
        "user0": {
            "uid": "1",
        },
        "user1": {
            "uid": "2",
        },
        "user2": {
            "uid": "3",
        },
        "userN": {
            "uid": "N",
        },
        "venue0": {
            "id": "1",
        },
        "venue1": {
            "id": "2",
        },
        "venue2": {
            "id": "3",
        },
        "venueN": {
            "id": "N",
        }
    }
}
```

Code:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, dynamic> Objects { get; set; }
}

RootObject deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data);
```

If you need to create `User` and `Venue` instances you can do something like this:

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();
List<Venue> venues = new List<Venue>();

foreach (string key in deserializedObject.Objects.Keys)
{
    if (key.StartsWith("user", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        users.Add(new User { Uid = deserializedObject.Objects[key].uid });
    }

    if (key.StartsWith("venue", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        venues.Add(new Venue { Id = deserializedObject.Objects[key].id });
    }
}
```

I think it's a mess but it works. Restructure your JSON if you can.

Comment: Thanks a lot! you really helped. Yes, I know it's terrible json, but to change it is not yet possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript serializer.

import namespace

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

And Use below code to deserialize your json string :

```
JavaScriptSerializer sr = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string jsondata = /*your json string here*/;
//Now with this line the Json string will be converted in MyObj1 object type
MyObj1 converted = sr.Deserialize<Object>(jsondata);
```

Refer [This](http://blog.shekharpro.com/2011/01/serializing-and-deserializing-data-from.html) Link for more information.

Comment: Thank for reply, but I work with Windows Phone 8 and the project is tied to Json.Net. And but if json contain obj5, obj6, obj7, obj8 etc?

Comment: are you getting any exception ?

Comment: no, if the json contain 10000 users, I must declare 10000 properties in class Objects. I'm looking for other ways to solve this problem.

Comment: you can use list property of the users. **public class List<User> users {get; set;}**

Comment: users or  venues (or other objects). I can't use List<object>. And the json don't contain list, only objects. JsonConvert can't deserialize it to List.